# $\cos\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)\geqslant \frac{\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(z)}{3}$ for $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x,y,z<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

I am trying to prove the inequality of the title, in vain so far.

It is easy to prove that $\cos$ is concave downward on $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ using differentiation, and this would imply the inequality, but I want to use only elementary (=preCalculus) tools for this inequality.

Also, using $\cos(x)+\cos(y)=2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})$, we obtain that $\frac{\cos(x)+\cos(y)}{2}\leq \cos(\frac{x+y}{2})$. Using the density of dyadic numbers and continuity of $\cos$, this implies that $\cos$ is concave downward on $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, but this does not fall into the category "preCalculus tools".

To sum up, what I can use is elementary trigonometry. Complex numbers can also be used.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from $\dfrac{\cos(x)+\cos(y)}{2}\leq \cos(\dfrac{x+y}{2}) \implies \\ \dfrac{\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(z)+\cos(t)}{4}\leq \cos(\dfrac{x+y+z+t}{4})$

let $ t=\dfrac{x+y+z}{3}$

$\dfrac{\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(z)+\cos(\dfrac{x+y+z}{3})}{4}\leq \cos(\dfrac{x+y+z}{3}) \implies \\ \dfrac{\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(z)}{3}\leq \cos(\dfrac{x+y+z}{3})$